# why am I getting only one name out of a CoreData entity?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

```
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender {

    entity = (Entity*)[NSEntityDescription
               insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entity"
               inManagedObjectContext:self.objectContext];

    entity.name = Name;

    for (int i =0 ; i< textfieldarray.count; i++) {

        Timeinday * timeinday = (Timeinday*)[NSEntityDescription
                          insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Timeinday"
                          inManagedObjectContext:self.objectContext];

        UITextField *timein = [textfieldarray objectAtIndex:i];


        timeinday.timeinday = timein.text;
        timeinday.name = entity;

    }

    NSError* error;

    [self.objectContext save:&error];
}
```

When I save when `textfieldarray.count` is greater than 1, `timeinday.name` is recorded only in one line, the rest of it are empty. Why?

Comment: What is the cardinality of the inverse relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a To-Many relationship on the Entity object for the Timeinday objects.  Something like Entity.times -->> Timeinday.  Set this to be the inverse of the To-One relationship Timeinday.name.

You might also want to consider some better naming conventions for you objects.